# What is the (theoretical!) order in performance of primitives in a Java equals method?

Tags: java, performance, equals, primitive, primitive-types

byte < short < int < long SEEMS to be the easy part.
They can simply be compared using "==" and they have all different bit length.

But do the different bit sizes even make a THEORETICAL difference on a 64 bit cpu that should be able to compare all those bits at ONCE?

And how EXACTLY do char, float and double fit in?
In an equals method, you need to use the static compare method to compare float and double, this will, on average, be SLOWER than a direct "==", but how exactly does that compare to the other types? What about char vs. short that both have the same bit length? Not to speak about the unspecified boolean bit length...

Comment: "*In an equals method, you need to use the static compare method to compare float and double...*" - You can compare `float`s and `double`s with `==` and it will do exactly what you think it does. But in general, you should not compare them with `==`, but see whether the difference between two `float`s/`double`s is below a certain `delta`.

Comment: I think I am right in saying that types like char, short and byte are converted internally to integers when any arithmetic operation is performed such as multiplication. So although the `==` comparison will not be impacted, since `equals` is contractually linked to the `hashCode` method and it's often common in hash code methods to do things like multiplication by a prime number, you might find that in theory it could take longer.

Comment: @DavidGoate you are right that, in the Java bytecode, there are no codes for data types `< int`. But, on a language level, calling `equals(...)` is absolutely independent from `hashCode()`.

Comment: @Turing85 you can't use deltas in an equals method. That would break the contract of equals(): a equals b and b equals c implies that a equals c. That won't work with deltas.

Comment: @JBNizet good point.

Comment: `Object.equals` includes a reference identity check with `==` (so I would assume it performs well).